# Fill Background Color entire TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}

#td_design {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td_design">
      asdasd<br/> asdsajsakj
      <br/> asdqjwhdksad
      <br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried putting a color on the body to test if the TD's Color actually expands through. Here's the result:

[image]

I know this can be fixed by adding the `id = "td_design"` on the `<table>` instead on the `<td>` but I can't since I want to add different `background-color` to each `td` . How can I make the TD's color extend to the whole page?

Comment: `I know this can be fixed...` what can be fixed? What's the issue? It's not clear what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Your code isn't enough to replicate the issue, I've edited your question and put the code into the snippet, this isn't the same as the img you upload. All we can do is guess like the answers below

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What you have IS filling the entire background. You need to adjust the default CSS for `<table>` and `<td>` pertaining to padding, borders, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables, by default, have some spacing between cells.

You can remove this spacing using one of the following:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
/* OR */
border-spacing: 0;
```

If your table has no borders then you can use whichever one you want. If you do start adding borders, then `collapse` will start merging borders together (which can lead to interesting effects...) while `border-spacing` will just put them side-by-side with no gap.

Here's some demos:

```css
table {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  background-color: black;
}
td {
  background-color: #cfc;
}

#tbl_2 {border-spacing: 0}
#tbl_3 {border-collapse: collapse}

#tbl_4 td {border: 1px solid #3cf}

#tbl_5 {border-spacing: 0}
#tbl_5 td {border: 1px solid #3cf}

#tbl_6 {border-collapse: collapse}
#tbl_6 td {border: 1px solid #3cf}

#tbl_7 {border-collapse: collapse}
#tbl_7 td {border: 1px solid #3cf}

td.red {
  border-color: #f66 !important;
  background-color: #fcc !important;
}
td.red.fix {
  border-style: double !important;
}
```

```html
Default
<table id="tbl_1"><tr><td>X1Y1</td><td>X2Y1</td></tr><tr><td>X1Y2</td><td>X2Y2</td></tr></table>

Spacing 0
<table id="tbl_2"><tr><td>X1Y1</td><td>X2Y1</td></tr><tr><td>X1Y2</td><td>X2Y2</td></tr></table>

Collapse
<table id="tbl_3"><tr><td>X1Y1</td><td>X2Y1</td></tr><tr><td>X1Y2</td><td>X2Y2</td></tr></table>

Default with cell borders
<table id="tbl_4"><tr><td>X1Y1</td><td>X2Y1</td></tr><tr><td>X1Y2</td><td class="red">X2Y2</td></tr></table>

Spacing 0 (note double width on middle borders, and blue/red together)
<table id="tbl_5"><tr><td>X1Y1</td><td>X2Y1</td></tr><tr><td>X1Y2</td><td class="red">X2Y2</td></tr></table>

Collapse (note loss of red borders in middle)
<table id="tbl_6"><tr><td>X1Y1</td><td>X2Y1</td></tr><tr><td>X1Y2</td><td class="red">X2Y2</td></tr></table>

Double-style "fix" to make the red border more "important" in collapse priority
<table id="tbl_7"><tr><td>X1Y1</td><td>X2Y1</td></tr><tr><td>X1Y2</td><td class="red fix">X2Y2</td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure in your css that you have all spacing and padding set to 0px

Answer (score 1):

**Try this code:**
I added different class as per requirement (different color for each TD).
added 3 classes namely `td_design1, td_design2 and td_design3` each with different color.

So this will call different class style for different table TD.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
body {
 background-color: #2c3e50;
}

#td_design1 {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#td_design2 {
  background-color: #559542;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
#td_design3 {
  background-color: #f00112;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}


</style>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id = "td_design1">
       asdasd
    </td>
    <td id = "td_design2">
       asdsajsakj
    </td>
    <td id = "td_design3">
       asdqjwhdksad
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What have you changed, why have you changed it, and how does it help? Code-only answers don't help much...

Comment: I really don't see how that solves the problem. Where is there any mention of having differently coloured table cells??

Comment: Please read the last statement of question carefully. middle row may be you will find there. //I want to add different background-color to each td

Answer (score -1):

remove border from tr / td, this seems to be a `border: 3px inset gray` or close to...

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#td_design {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.withBorder {
  border: 3px inset gray;
}
.withoutBorder{
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="td_design">
      <h5>default navigator style</h5>
      asdasd<br/> asdsajsakj
      <br/> asdqjwhdksad
      <br/>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="td_design" class=withBorder>
      <h5>with border styled</h5>
      asdasd<br/> asdsajsakj
      <br/> asdqjwhdksad
      <br/>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="td_design" class=withoutBorder>
      <h5>with border none (like many browsers default)</h5>
      asdasd<br/> asdsajsakj
      <br/> asdqjwhdksad
      <br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```